# Running Scala 3 Tests in Intellij

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, sbt, scalatest, scala-3

I have a SBT project that is written in Scala 3. I am attempting to run the tests (written in Scalatest) in debug mode in Intellij.

I have tried a couple different approaches, and thus far, I either get some sort of exception, or the breakpoints aren't being honored.

What I have tried:

1. Setting up a Scalatest run configuration (both using sbt and otherwise) in Intellij
2. Starting a debug session in sbt in a separate terminal and attempting to attach to it via a Remote JVM Debug
3. Starting a session using the sbt Shell in IJ, and attempting to attach (I guess this is really the same as #2, it just eliminates an extra window)
4. Setting up an SBT Task configuration in Intellij, and setting the command to `~testOnly`

Approach #1 results in the following exception

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/scalatest/tools/Runner
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.scalaTest.ScalaTestRunner.runScalaTest2or3(ScalaTestRunner.java:43)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.scalaTest.ScalaTestRunner.main(ScalaTestRunner.java:26)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.scalatest.tools.Runner
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 2 more
```

Approach #2 and #3 ran the tests, but did not stop at any breakpoints.

Approach #4 hug when trying to build the project.

If it helps, the project consists of several ScalaJS lambdas, with a bunch of tests written in Scalatests.

Has anyone had any success with doing this before?

Comment: Is this project cross-compiled for several Scala versions (e.g. 2.12, 2.13 besides 3) or platforms (JVM, Scala.js, Scala Native)?

Comment: Yes, it is cross-compiled for Scala.js. After discussing internally, we have identified that this is likely the problem. We haven't adjusted our build to be able to account for this yet.